# Download file cause issue for streaming in ios

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, avplayer

I am using Live streaming with AVPlayer in my app & works fine.

But when I try to download some file using `Alamofire.downlaod method` then stream is stop working.

The `rate` property of `AVPlayer` is **zero automatically.**

**I think there may be some issue with threading but I am not getting it.**

**My Code is as Follow**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    play_Live_Stream()
}


override func viewWillAppear() {

    Download_favourite_files()
}

func Download_favourite_files() {
    for int i in arr_favourites{
        Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination).response { response in
            print(response)
        }
    }
    
}

func play_Live_Stream(){
    myplayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url as! URL)
    myPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: myplayerItem)
    myPlayer.volume = volume_slider.value
    PlayerObserving = true
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playInstalled(noti:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemPlaybackStalled, object: myPlayer.currentItem)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playfailed(noti:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTime, object: myPlayer.currentItem)
    myPlayer.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    myPlayer.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: [.new,.old,.initial], context: nil)
    myPlayer.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .new, context: nil)

}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        
    if ((object! as AnyObject).isEqual(myPlayer.currentItem) && keyPath=="status"){
        if myPlayer.status == AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay{
            print("ReadyToPlay")
          
            myPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

**TRY 2 (Default NSURLSession)**

```
func load_downloads(){
    for track in arr_tracks{
                
        let urlString = BASE_URL + "/track/download/" + "\(track.id)"
        print("downloaded url",urlString)
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let downloadTask = backgroundSession.downloadTask(with: url as! URL)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
}


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let destinationURLForFile = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent((downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent)! + "_" + (downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename)!)
    
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){
    }
    else{
        do {
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location as URL, to: destinationURLForFile as URL)
        }catch{
            print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
        }
    }
    
}
```

But it does not giving me any info for why stream is stop.
I also observing Stalled & failed info if any.

Comment: can you show the implementation of `play_Live_Stream`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, I added code of playing stream.

Comment: How many files are you downloading at once? Instead of starting all the downloads at once, can you try downloading one at a time? Maybe you're saturating your connection. Do you observe any changes to `playbackLikelyToKeepUp`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman, I am downloading around 5 files rightnow. I didn't get any changes to `playbackLikelyToKeepUp`. **But I am getting changes to `rate` to `0` , so player is pause automatically & never resume again even though download finished** May be you are right, let me try to download one at a time.

Comment: @user2526811 Can you try to play live stream with some delay?

Comment: @Wos, No I am playing immediately. it works fine if I off download.

Answer (score 0):

Try to play the stream on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self]
 self.play_Live_Stream()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play the stream on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
for int i in arr_favourites{
     Alamofire.download(urlString, to: destination).response { response in
         print(response)
     }
   }
}
```